# Should April Fools' Day questions be only asked on Meta?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

One April Fools' Day question ([How to deal with a program that has become self aware? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561112/how-to-deal-with-a-program-that-has-become-self-aware/2564484#2564484)) has been closed four times. Are twenty people wrong, or should it be migrated to Meta?

Answer (score 7):

It should be closed as "too localized", because it was only (if at all) relevant at a very specific moment in time that now has passed.

Comment: As the end of March draws nigh, it is relevant to ask: should it be reopened this coming Friday? (Note that it's also a Friday) Or even better, should it be re-opened every April 1st? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Twenty people *are* wrong.

The nineteen who've voted to reopen, plus the spare we can anticipate any moment now.

Why?

Because (as we have seen) if you treat 1April jokes as reasonable there is no end to the number that will be asked.

*Crush them!* I say, **crush them all!**

Comment: Some April 1st jokes were *actually* programming-related though, and resembled real questions.  I wouldn't compare those with the endless stream of Unicorn questions and/or pop-culture references.  IMO, it's not an issue with April 1st questions, it's just another manifestation of the bikeshed effect with this *specific* question.

Comment: @Aaronaught Well. Maybe  rage a little less at those. But only a *little*

Answer (score 2):

That question doesn't relate to any of the Stack Overflow trilogy of sites, even tangentially, so it's correctly closed and not migrated to Meta.

They could have gone either off-topic or not a real question. They just went with the latter.

Comment: Not even super user or server fault?